# x-times not-comparitive adjective

Tags: adjectives, emphasis

Can anyone confidently assert that "x-times" can be used preceding an adjective that is **not** comparative? It's role would be simple emphasis, like "very." Here are thought up examples. I cannot find any satisfying real-life usage.

1. You are ten-times beautiful.
2. The concert was a thousand-times amazing.
3. I am a hundred-times forgetful.
4. It is hard to look you in your a thousand-times stormy eyes.

Thanks!

Comment: *You are ten-times unique* is quite grammatical enough.  Personally I think using *unique* in a comparative sense ought to be a hanging offence, but that's battle I lost long ago.

Comment: It's a bit yucky though. Like the suddenly ubiquitous 'in a heartbeat'.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian so you've been seeing x-times ___ a lot? or are you talking about ten-times unique specifically?

Comment: No. I don't think I've seen it before in any context.

Comment: so maybe it's just my sentences that are yucky

Comment: Well sure, the sentences are indeed yucky, but that doesn't mean they are ungrammatical or that a question about their grammaticality is unwelcome.

Comment: 'Thrice beautiful' etc have been used in rather old poetry, but I'd say these strings are far from idiomatic. Have you checked 'three times beautiful' say for frequency of use in Google and Google ngram searches? (There may be proper noun complications.)

Comment: Yes, there are quite a bit of results for "thousand times beautiful," "hundred times beautiful," and "thousand times guilty," "thousand times wonderful." Obviously some numbers give no results, but I wonder if it is weird to use this with other adjectives, mainly negative ones, most of which give no results. Like x-times furious, or x-times grumpy. Although 1000-times horrible gives two results, which I guess is not a lot.

Comment: The grading of 'ungradeable' adjectives – extreme (eg _freezing_), absolute (eg _dead_) and even classifying (eg _nuclear_) (and even attributive nouns, as in _steam_ locomotive) has been discussed before. It is non-standard,quirky ... but not unknown. Would it be rejected by a teacher / editor ...  – probably.

Comment: Reserve it for poetry or lyrics, where *unbreak my heart* is just the right amount of wrong, and says something piercing that standard language may miss. Your phrasing sticks out -- use where that is a plus.

Answer (score 1):

You might refer to a great boxing champion as "the five times challenged but never beaten N" - that would be idiomatic, though there would probably be a better way.  Most times you'll do this, though, you'll be dealing with one, two or three occasions, and then you might use once, twice or thrice - "twice cooked chips" / "thrice blessed".

Comment: What I mean here is x-times in order to emphasize an adjective that does **not** have to do with an actual repetition. 5-times challenged or twice cooked imply that the noun being described was in fact challenged five times, or cooked twice, whereas 3-times beautiful does not suggest any repeated action. It is not three-times beautified, but three-times beautiful.